# Galaxy s3 stuck in reboot loop after root

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Today I attempted to root my galaxy s3 with iRoot for android. My phone restarted during the rooting process, but now it keeps looping over and over. I have tried resetting the cache and even factory resetting it (by booting it up in recovery mode), but after the reset the same reboot logo appears. Any help at this point would be great.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't install custom recovery Use [Odin Flash Tool](http://stockromfile.com/odin-flash-tool-download-version/) for custom recovery and you need Stock Rom or custom rom from any website

Answer (score -2):

Did you install a custom recovery? If not, please install something like [TWRP](https://twrp.me/) or CWM. For Samsung phones, you can use the [ODIN](http://www.droidviews.com/download-odin-tool-for-samsung-galaxy-devices-all-versions/) tool. You will also need a custom or stock rom that you will be flashing. A high level guideline would be:

1. Using [ODIN](http://www.droidviews.com/download-odin-tool-for-samsung-galaxy-devices-all-versions/), install custom recovery.
2. Flash your ROM (factory or custom). [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) is a good resource.

Comment: Some enlightment would be how installing a custom recovery solves the issue of the device being stuck in a boot loop. There's no indication OP has this issue while booting into recovery mode – and a broken recovery should have no effect on booting into "normal mode". OK, you continue with flashing a ROM – but why should so drastic steps be necessary? Wouldn't e.g. a factory-reset suffice? What should be fixed by flashing a ROM (without wipe), as that would only overwrite what's read-only anyway?